# Xcode keeps crashing on startup

Tags: xcode, startup, crash

I have a 13" machbook pro 2011 model. For some reason when I launch xcode it displays the start box where you can choose to create a new application or open a previous one but if you try to go any further such as create a new application or open a old one then it crashes, giving the error. Please use the below link to go to pastebin and see the error in question. (pastebin was used as the error was too long to fit into this post)

[Error Report](http://pastebin.com/jvqbqnyf)

I have tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it, this works for 1 or 2 times and then it starts crashing again.

Can anyone help me with this??

P.s I am competent with computing but have just become a mac user so if theres anything specific to macs thats mentioned (i.e nothing I will of come across on a Windows PC) then can you try to word your answers in the simplest form. Also I am using Xcode 4.2.1.

Many thanks,
J

Comment: If reinstalling works for 1 or 2 times, maybe there is something that corrupts xcode templates.

Comment: i have the exact same problem. please update if you found a solution:)